# When do 0-preserving isometries have to be linear?

Tags: vector-spaces, norms, isometries

Let $\langle \mathbf{V},+,\cdot,||.|| \rangle$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $f : \mathbf{V} \to \mathbf{V}$ be an isometry that satisfies $f(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ .

What conditions on the vector space would or would not force $f$ to be linear?

examples: finite dimensional, complete, norm induced by an inner product, strictly convex

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%2DUlam_theorem

Comment: I feel ... somewhat silly, although I would not have been able to find that on my own.  I'll accept that if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Ricky, I wouldn't worry too much. One of the goals of MO, in my opinion, is to match up people with natural (and good!) questions to people who happen to know the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you assume $f$ to be surjective then $f$ has to be linear without any assumptions on $V$ by the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%2DUlam_theorem). Wikipedia doesn't offer much more information than a link to the beautiful recent [proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20180516125105/http://www.helsinki.fi/~jvaisala/mazurulam.pdf) by J. Väisälä.

Comment: There is a nice generalization of the Mazur-Ulam theorem due to Figiel, T. Figiel, On nonlinear isometric embedding of normed linear spaces, Bull. Acad. Polon. Sei. Ser. Sei. Math. Astronom. Phys. 16 (1968), 185-188.

If $f$ is an isometric embedding of the Banach space $X$ into the Banach space $Y$ and $f(0)=0$, then $X$ embeds isometrically isomorphically as a norm one complemented subspace of the closed linear span of  $f[X]$.

Comment: Thank you Bill, this is indeed very nice! I'll have a closer look at it later.